# iOS Facebook SDK: FBSDKGraphRequest not getting email, despite permission

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using FB SDK v4.4 (latest) and think I have avoided the gotchas in the other questions.

I am establishing a logIn:

```
       FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
       [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] 
           handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
           if (error) {
              // Process error
           } else {
              [self facebookGetUserProfileWithCompletion:completion];
           }
       }];
```

I've specifically asked for "email" (an extended permission that requires app review).

My app has passed review, and the user gives permission for email when prompted. Adding a `[result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]` check in the handler returns TRUE.

Once the user's has responded to the UI, the code then gets the user profile from Graph API:

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields" : @"id,email,first_name,last_name,link,locale"}]  
              startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

if (!error) {
     NSString *email = [result objectForKey:@"email"] ;
     NSString *first_name = [result objectForKey:@"first_name"] ;
     //etc...
}
```

At this point, I have just *five* parameters; I am missing email. Using Graph API Explorer, I get the full six. The user does have an email address registered with FB.

Why no email???!!!

Comment: `email` permission does not need review, it is one of the three permissions that are approved by default; `user_birthday` however does require review. // Since all other five fields you are requesting are part of the public profile, and only email needs an additional permission, I’d suggest that you first of all log the access token that gets used for the request, and then check it using the FB debug tool.

Comment: Good suggestion. I did that, and got some strange inconsistencies. Logging into the app via an FB account that associated with the FB developer account, I got a message saying the app needs review. Of course it was reviewed in June of 2014. Does it need another review every year? Or do you need a review when moving from SDK v3.x to v4.x?

Comment: Following up, it looks like things have changed since my last review to do with user_birthday. The app still returns DOB, but they are now pushing to minimize use of that (finally!). I can get age_range from public profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've pretty much resolved my issues. Here they are:

1) @cbroe had the most helpful suggestion of getting the token and using Graph API Explorer to debug. Lots of help there.

2) FB are shifting their DOB field to age_range in most cases. It seems that my existing app will still return DOB, but the new version will not without permission. No doc on this I could find, but if I go with age_range, I'm good.

3) There was a strange problem with my email address in my FB test account. That's fixed, and I am getting email again no problem. Again, the Graph API test was most helpful in resolving this. Thanks again @cbroe!

Comment: `user_birthday` was always needed to get the user’s DOB. Most likely your app with which it “works” simply has that, because it was granted at some point earlier? // And no (regarding your other comment), apps don’t need to go through review “every year” or something like that; but if you add new permissions to the scope that you did not ask for earlier and that were not reviewed yet, then you need to send _those_ in for review.

Comment: I double checked; my app does not have an official approval for user_birthday. Just public_actions and user_friends (plus user_email and public_profile, of course). I think DOB was public profile a year ago, and they switched at some point. Either way, much appreciate the help.

Comment: can you share some !! regarding Api call for fetching email

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters should be just one string

```
@"fields:id,email,first_name,last_name,link,locale"
```

Comment: This doesn't compile... It seems to be looking for a Dictionary with two variables (field and field-list, I'm assuming). Plus I *am* getting five of the six values returned, so I'm doing something right. 
Can anyone point to Facebook's doc on this? I can't find it anywhere...!